# Why WSO2 ESB Error Codes Are Not Specific with Different Scenarios

Tags: error-handling, wso2, wso2-esb

I am facing a issue in WSO2 ESB regarding exception handling. I have noticed that WSO2 ESB is not returning specific Error_Codes in different error scenarios. It is returning Error_Code '0' in case of endpoint failure and also in case of XSLT transformation error.

Can any expert from WSO2 explain it. Because it is very annoying that WSO2 ESB can't handle very simple error scenarios. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If we see the latest documentation of wso2 esb 4.8.1, WSO2 has defined error codes for only Transport errors and endpoint failures. 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Error+Handling

So, for other scenarios like message validation errors or xslt transformation errors there are no pre-defined error codes from WSO2.It is annoying but we just have to live with it.. :)